# Mouse not working after installing 14.04 LTS 64bit

Tags: mouse

After new install Ubuntu 14.04 after login screen mouse becomes disabled. Mouse worked just fine up until after login screen. How can mouse issue be corrected?

Answer (score 1):

Start Terminal by pressing **Ctrl+Alt+T**

Enter these lines in the terminal

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```